# How can I make the contours of quadratic form using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I have the following quadratic form f(x) = x^T A x - b^T x and i've used numpy to define my matrices A, b:

```py
A = np.array([[4,3], [3,7]])
b = np.array([3,-7])
```

So we're talking about 2 dimensions here, meaning that the contour plot will have the axes x1 and x2 and I want these to span from -4 to 4.

I've tried to experiment by doing

```py
u = np.linspace(-4,4,100)
x, y = np.meshgrid(u,u)
```

in order to create the 2 axis x1 and x2 but then I dont know how to define my function f(x) and if I do `plt.contour(x,y,f)` it won't work because the function f(x) is defined with only x as an argument.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks !

---

**EDIT** : I managed to "solve" the problem by doing the operations between the quadratic form , for example x^T A x, and ended up with a function of x1,x2 where these are the components of x vector. After that I did

```
u = np.linspace(-4,4,100)
x, y = np.meshgrid(u,u)
z = 1.5*(x**2) + 3*(y**2) - 2*x + 8*y + 2*x*y #(thats the function i ended up with)
plt.contour(x, y, z)
```

Answer (score 1):

If Your transformation matrices A, b look like

```py
A = np.array([[4,3], [3,7]])
b = np.array([3,-7])
```

and Your data look like

```
u = np.linspace(-4,4,100)
x, y = np.meshgrid(u,u)
x.shape
```

x and y will have the shapes `(100,100)`.

You can define  f(x) as

```py
def f(x):
    return np.dot(np.dot(x.T,A),x) - np.dot(b,x)
```

to then input anything with the shape (2, N) into the function f.
I am unfortunately not sure, which values You want to feed into it.
But one example would be: [(-4:4),  (-4:4)]

```py
plt.contour(x, y, f(x[0:2,:]))
```

### update

If the visualization of the contour plot does not fit Your purpose, You can use other plots, e.g. 3D visualizations.

```py
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D # This import has side effects required for the kwarg projection='3d' in the call to fig.add_subplot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(40,20))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x,y, f(x[0:2,:]))
plt.show()
```

If You expect other values in the z-dimension, the projection `f` might be off.
For other 3d plots see: https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The first 2 arguments of the "contour" function are the axes of my contour plot ? I thought they were supposed to be the points at which I will calculate the value of the 3rd argument (the function). Also, I want to feed every point there is. Meaning for x from -4 to 4 and y from -4 to 4.  Thats where my problem is. How can I get the value of f for every point in this grid?

Comment: Yeah your example is for the values I requested. However when you run it the resulting contours arent ellipsoids as they are supposed to be. :/ Any ideas why?

Comment: The contour plot projects three dimensions onto two and codes the third in colors. The colors represent the values of z (third dimension) relative to its min and max.
I updated my answer to inlcude a 3D plot, which i guessed might help. If You like the answer now, accept it for others to find it easier.

Comment: Thanks Antihead. The problem is as  I said that the code you provided does give the correct contours of the quadratic form. The contours of a quadratic form are always ellipsoids. In anycase, I solved my problem by making operations between the matrices and ending up with  a function of x1,x2 where x1 and x2 are the components of x-vector. After that, the contours were correct. Guess i'll edit my question and add the answer

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = np.array([[4,3], [3,7]])
n_points = 100

u = np.linspace(-4, 4, n_points)
x, y = np.meshgrid(u, u)

X = np.vstack([x.flatten(), y.flatten()])
f_x = np.dot(np.dot(X.T, A), X)
f_x = np.diag(f_x).reshape(n_points, n_points)

plt.figure()
plt.contour(x, y, f_x)
```

Another alternative is to compute `f_x` as follows.

```
f_x = np.zeros((n_points, n_points))
for i in range(n_points):
    for j in range(n_points):
        in_v = np.array([[x[i][j]], [y[i][j]]])
        f_x[i][j] = np.dot(np.dot(in_v.T, A), in_v)
```